# Стопроцентно(?)выигрышный — правописание

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Как правильно — слитно, раздельно или через дефис?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***стопроцентно-выигрышный.***

По образцу: беспроцентно-выигрышный, процентно-выигрышный.

Два слова равноправны, **сочинительная** связь, поэтому пишутся через дефис.

**Хороший** процент!

**СТОПРОЦЕНТНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. Содержащий сто процентов чего-л. С. раствор. С-ая шерсть.

Comment: Тогда плюс вашему.

Answer (score 1):

***Стопроцентно выигрышный, или Выигрышный (насколько?) стопроцентно.***

Ни слитного, ни дефисного нарисания не существует. А раздельно потому, что между прилагательным и наречием можно задать вопрос, а также вставить слово, например:

***Стопроцентно нами выигрышный***.

Comment: Мне *кажется*, что надо править: *нарисания* и *нами*. Выигранный (кем?) нами. Выигрышный (для кого?) для нас, для меня, для всех. А как быть вот с этим дефисным написанием? ***Стопроцентно-совместимый*** (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/84738/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Comment: Я это задал вообще из-за слова *беспроцентно-выигрышный*.